# Uploading client's file from server (spring boot application deployed on compute engine) to google bucket

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload my client's file from springboot application deployed on gcp compute engine to google bucket. Below code uploads that file into bucket but gives error:

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(GCP_AUTHENTICATION_FILE);
InputStream dbAsStream = resource.getInputStream();
String bucketName = GCP_BUCKET_NAME;
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(dbAsStream))
                .setProjectId(GCP_PROJECT_ID).build().getService();
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, fileName);
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
storage.create(blobInfo, ClientFile.getBytes());
```

Error:

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.api.client.util.DateTime com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject.getCustomTime()'
```

Comment: From the data at hand I would guess that the GCP library you are using is expecting StorageObject to have a method `getCustomTime` that doesnt exist.  Perhaps you have a mismatch between GCP and the version of the GCP library you are using.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I used 5.22.0 gcp version in BOM.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Gavin, the GCP library you are using is expecting StorageObject to have a method getCustomTime that doesn't exist. Confirm if you have a mismatch between GCP and the version of the GCP library you are using.